# Can probability in the context of a normal distribution be interpreted as a proportion?

Tags: probability, statistics, self-learning

I am trying to "hunt down" an error in reasoning that came up during a discussion with one of my colleagues. Let $X \sim N(\mu_x,\sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_y,\sigma^2)$. I am interested in $P(X>Y) - P(X<Y) = 2 P(X>Y) - 1$ and more specifically, in the variance of this quantity. In my view, this variance would be far from straightforward and might not even have a closed form expression. My colleague reasoned that because essentially $P(X>Y)$ is a proportion of observations where one group is better than the other, we can restate the problem in terms of Bernoulli distribution, denote this probability as $\pi$ and express the quantity of interest as $2 \pi - 1$. Then, the variance expression becomes straightforward: $Var (2 \pi - 1) = Var (2 \pi) = 4 Var(\pi) = 4 \frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{N}$ I know that the reasoning is wrong, and several simulations have confirmed this, but I cannot put my finger on where it goes wrong. I wonder if anyone might spot it? Thank you.

Comment: 1) are $X$ and $Y$ independent here? 2) You speak of variance, but the variance of which random variable? Note that $2P(X>Y)-1$ is just a real number (at most a degenerated random variable with variance $0$). Maybe $2\mathbf1_{X>Y}-1$? Then it is okay go for Bernoulli approach.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. And the variance I am looking for is the difference between two quantities, let's call it $\delta = P(X>Y)-P(X<Y)$. In the context of a study comparing two samples, the two probabilities will vary from one set of samples to the other, meaning that $\delta$ will inevitably vary as well. This is the variance I am looking for.

Comment: @drhab, the idea is exactly as you write. Use $E[{1}_{X>Y}]$ instead of $P(X>Y)$. However, the variance obtained through this approach is over 120 times lower than the observed variance over 10000 simulated datasets. So there must be a problem I think

Comment: The quantity $\delta$ will only vary if the parameters $\mu_x,\mu_y,\sigma$ vary. I am familiar with probability theory and not so much with statistics and do not really understand what you mean with "two probabilities will vary from one set of samples to the other". My impulsive reaction is: samples will vary, but probabilities do not (if distributions stay the same).

Comment: I am working in statistics, so nothing is fixed for me :) The underlying probabilities will stay the same you are right, but not knowing the true value of these probabilities I would have to resort to estimating them from the data. And there the estimates of my parameters $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$, $\sigma$ will vary slightly from sample to sample simply due to chance. Their distribution will be centered around the true parameter, but I might get some extreme values from time to time.

Comment: I have added the tag "statistics" (if you don't mind of course) to your question. I cannot help you out, and hope someone else can.

Comment: Not at all. Thank you!